# how to interpret cnn results

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm new in deep learning and neural networks, so now after finishing a tutorial in youtube I tried to run a code of a liveness face detection (training), here it's the code:

```
from livenessnet import LivenessNet
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from imutils import paths
from keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import dlib
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

model_path = 'liveness_model.h5'

# initialize the initial learning rate, batch size, and number of
# epochs to train for
INIT_LR = (1e-5)/4
BS = 32
EPOCHS = 20

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../db_faces/train',
                                                 target_size=(64,64),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=BS,
                                                 class_mode='sparse',
                                                 shuffle=True)

validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../db_faces/test',
                                                 target_size=(64,64),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=BS,
                                                 class_mode='sparse',
                                                 shuffle=False)
 
labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
print(labels)
# initialize the optimizer and model
adam_opt = Adam(lr = INIT_LR, decay = INIT_LR/EPOCHS)
model = LivenessNet.build(width=64, height=64, depth=3,
    classes=len(labels))

model.summary()

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
#configure the learning process
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= adam_opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience = 5 )

step_size_train = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
step_size_validation = validation_generator.samples // validation_generator.batch_size

# train the network
print("[INFO] training network for {} epochs...".format(EPOCHS))
H = model.fit(train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   validation_data = validation_generator,
                   validation_steps = step_size_validation,
                   epochs=EPOCHS,
                   callbacks = [early_stopping]
                    )

# save the network to disk
print("[INFO] serializing network to '{}'...".format(model_path))
model.save(model_path)

print("[INFO] Class indices")
labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
print(labels)

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(H.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(H.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(H.history['loss'])
plt.plot(H.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

Y_pred = model.predict(validation_generator, validation_generator.samples // BS + 1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Fake', 'Real']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
```

so after the execution I got this 2 graphs and a classification report with a confusion matrix:
[image: model accuracy]
[image: model loss]

and this is the matrix and the classification report :

```
Confusion Matrix
[[1436  234]
 [  14 1461]]

Classification Report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support
           0       0.99      0.86      0.92      1670
           1       0.86      0.99      0.92      1475
    accuracy                           0.92      3145
   macro avg       0.93      0.93      0.92      3145
weighted avg       0.93      0.92      0.92      3145
```

so what I have to get as a conclusion ? and is this result good or not ?

Comment: maybe you should ask on similar portal but for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your results are good as you see f1-score ranges from 0 to 1 higher the value, better the results and your score is 0.92 so that's pretty good, whereas for the loss, it should be as close to 0 as possible but it does not have a range from 0 to 1.

Precision is the ratio of true positives( your model predicted true and actually is also true) and total positives i.e. true positives + false positives( false positives = your model predicted positive but actually were not)
In simple terms, it basically tells us what are the chances of its prediction to be correct if it predicts True. For example, your model has precision of 0.99 for class 0 so if it predicts class 0 then there are 99% chances that the prediction is correct.

Recall is the ratio of True Positives and True Positives + False Negatives. For all the class 0 who actually belonged to class 0, recall tells us how many your model correctly identified as belonging to class 0.

It's a bit confusing but read some articles or watch some youtube videos, you'll get it.